# M-AUDIO Keystation 88es is Unknown Device on Windows7 64 SP1

Tags: midi

I've been using MIDI "M-AUDIO Keystation 88es" for more than 4 years on my PC. Yesterday I tried to connect the MIDI keyboard to my notebook (Windows 7 64bit SP1). I had installed the current driver *"USB_MIDI_Series_Installer_5_0_1_Driver_5_10_0_5139"* to the OS and connected MIDI via USB. But in Device Manager, the **midi keyboard looks like *"Unknown Device"***. I can't play on notebook, but it's ok on PC (OS is -Windows 7 64bit SP1 too). How can I fix this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Things you can try (and which have been known to work one time or another) include:

- Download the latest driver from the company's web site, install it, reconnect the keyboard and try again.
- Sometimes it will say that the device doesn't need a driver and it should just plug and play. That may or may not be correct. If you can still find a driver, try it.
- Try a different USB port. If the keyboard draws power from the USB port, it could be that the current notebook's USB port isn't supplying enough power to the keyboard. Some USB ports may have more power than others, and desktops more than laptops.
- If you're using a different cable on different machines, try with the cable that is known to work on the PC.
- Remove the "unknown device" from Windows' device manager and run a machine scan (so the device is recognized once again and reinstalled)
- At the end of the day, downloading the right driver from the manufacturer's web site is probably your best bet